# Compare time slots with available time slot

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have booked time slots 8-10.00, 8-8.15, 8.10-8.35, etc then available slots are 8-8.15,8.15-8.30,8.30-8.45, etc I want to check that booked time is not encountering the available slot.

```
if ( (isset($strTYm_array[$i])) && testRange($Worker_slots_times[$k], $Worker_slots_ends[$k], $strTYm_array[$i],$endTYm_array[$i])) {
    if ((( $Worker_slots_ends[$k] + @$serviceBreaks[$Worker_booked_slots_ftn[$k]]) <= $endTYm) && (($Worker_slots_ends[$k]+  @$serviceBreaks[$Worker_booked_slots_ftn[$k]]+ $bk_ttime +  $duration_of_work) <= $endTYm)) {
        $strTYm_array[$i] = $Worker_slots_ends[$k] + @$serviceBreaks[$Worker_booked_slots_ftn[$k]];
        $endTYm_array[$i] = $strTYm_array[$i] + $duration_of_work + $bk_ttime;
        $endTYm_array_withoutBreak[$i] = $strTYm_array[$i] + $duration_of_work;
    } else if (isset($strTYm_array[$i])) {
        for ($s= $i; $s < count($strTYm_array); $s++ ) {
            unset($strTYm_array[$s]);
            unset($endTYm_array[$s]);
            unset($endTYm_array_withoutBreak[$s]);
        }
    }
}

function testRange ($Booked_start_time1, $booked_end_time1, $available_start_time2, $available_end_time2) {
    if ($booked_end_time1 <= $available_start_time2) {
        return true;
    } elseif ($Booked_start_time1 >= $available_start_time2 && $Booked_start_time1 >= $available_end_time2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

above function is using for weather booked slot is overlapping available slot but this fails when the booked slot is 8.00 - 10.00 and the available slot is 8.10 - 8.30. so i need to satisfy all the condition

Comment: I have cleaned up and simplified your snippet without changing its functionality. (this is not a resolving change)  Please [edit] your question to include a realistic call of `testRange()`.  This way we can see the exact quality of the values in each variable/arguement.

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa can u please help me to sort this issue

Comment: @mickmackusa updated the code . pls review it

Comment: My point is that volunteers cannot confidently test your snippet and their own tests because they don't know the exact values of `$Worker_slots_times[$k]`, `$Worker_slots_ends[$k]`, `$strTYm_array[$i]`, and `$endTYm_array[$i]`

Comment: Then you may edit your question to create a [mcve], then post an educational resolving answer; or you can more simply retract/delete your question.